# ssh force user to user ssh-add

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I am trying to understand how this functionality works.  I have digital ocean account.  I have given digital ocean an ssh public key to associate with any server that I spin up.  Once I've created a droplet if I try to ssh as root to the server it fails, but if I do an ssh-add and give it a the specific key that I defined with my digital ocean account then it allows me to log in.  If I were to add another user account and put a different public key in that accounts authorized_hosts file I would be able to log in without using ssh-add.

Can someone explain to me how this functionality works?  How do I force a user to use ssh-add?

EDIT:  I did a verbose ssh, it seems to only try these keys, but not any of the other keys that I have in my .ssh directory including the one I have setup for digital ocean.  That I suspect may be part of the problem.

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

Comment: Or you could just force login with the explicit keyfile: `ssh -i /home/foo/.ssh/id_rsa_digitalisland root@server.example.org`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think conceptually you're confusing the idea of running an SSH agent versus adding a key to an already-running SSH agent.

Normally, the workflow for adding a SSH key to a session is as follows:

1. Execute ssh-agent $SHELL, where $SHELL could be `bash`, `zsh` etc. as in `ssh-agent bash`
2. Associate the specific private key to the agent shell session using `ssh-add`
3. Connect to whatever host has the specific public key for the private 
   key you're using in your shell session in `authorized_hosts`.

Note that you can use `ssh-add -l` at any time to see what keys you have loaded.

So in this case, the reason you're able to connect is that you're using `ssh-add` to add your key into your current session, which will automatically be checked when you attempt to ssh via `account@host`

You can see an example of this checking if you add verbosity flags to your SSH attempt using `-v(vvv)`:

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/patrick/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
```

With `-v` only, I get the following: (adding more v's increases the amount of debug verbosity you get)

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/patrick/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

The reason your initial SSH session is failing without doing an `ssh-add` may be because your key is stored in a specific directory that isn't checked by default via SSH. However when you execute `ssh-add` you're adding the key to the entire session, and SSH knows to use that by default instead of searching `~/.ssh` or somewhere else.

According to the [SSH manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh):

> -i identity_file
>
> Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for RSA or DSA >authentication is read. The default is ~/.ssh/identity
>   for protocol version 1, and ~/.ssh/id_rsa and ~/.ssh/id_dsa for
>   protocol version 2. Identity files may also be specified on a per-host
>   basis in the configuration file. It is possible to have multiple -i
>   options (and multiple identities specified in configuration files).

So if your key is named something that's not the above filenames, or in a different location, SSH won't see it unless you specifically use the `-i` flag to indicate the path and filename, or you use `ssh-add` to add it to your session.

You can test this theory by using the `-i` flag with SSH to test your key. If you were to execute `ssh -i $KEYLOCATION account@host` you should get a successful login.

Double check that your private key file is in `~/.ssh` and named id_rsa or whatever keytype it may be. Having that will probably mean you don't have to execute `ssh-add` in the future.

Comment: I edited my initial question with more information.  I store all my keys in .ssh including my digital ocean key, so the question is why does it not see that key until I add it.

Comment: Ok, so I just created a new key, and a new user and named the key id_testkey_rsa and it failed to see the key.  For some reason I thought the name of the key didn't matter and ssh would try all keys in the .ssh directory no matter the name, so thank you for taking the time to answer the question instead of just voting it down like one of the first 3 people to view the question.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it figured out. :)